# PHP pagination with page limit

Tags: php, pagination, limit

I want to limit the pages out of the total number of pages.

- Example: `1 2 3 4 5 6 >> out of 30`
- Example2: `<< 5 6 7 8 9 10 >> out of 30`

Here is my code:

```
$page = !empty($_GET['page']) ? (int) $_GET['page'] : 1;
// records per page
$per_page = 5;
// total records in database
$total_count = Mp3_Model::count_all();
// instantating the $pagination
$pagination = new Pagination($page, $per_page, $total_count);
// find the records for this page
$sql = "SELECT * FROM mp3 ";
$sql .= " LIMIT {$per_page} ";
$sql .= " OFFSET {$pagination->offset()}";
$mp3s = Mp3_Model::find_by_sql($sql);
foreach ($mp3s as $mp3) { 
   echo $mp3->titlu;
}
```

and this is the pagination:

```
<?php
    if ($pagination->total_pages() > 1) {

        if ($pagination->has_previous_page()) {
            echo '<li><a href="?page=' . $pagination->previous_page() . '">&laquo;</a></li>';
        }

        for ($i = 1; $i <= $pagination->total_pages(); $i++) {
            echo '<li';
            if ($_GET['page'] == $i) {
                echo ' class="active"';
            }
            echo '><a href="' . URL . 'mp3?page=' . $i . '">' . $i . '</a></li>';
        }

        if ($pagination->has_next_page()) {
            echo '<li><a href="?page=' . $pagination->next_page() . '">&raquo; </a></li>';
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: If this question is solved by yourself, please post your own answer to this question as it might be useful to others.. the text you'd like to have is easy as you already have the answer in your code! The simple answer is: `echo 'out of ' . $total_count; // total count is your last page...` OR if you'd like to have a `$var` that does the trick: `$Out_Of = 'out of  ' .  $total_count; // Add this line below $total_count = Mp3_Model::count_all();` I hope this will help you out for the "out of 30" problem.. I'll post an answer to the question if you reply and the issue isn't solved... Good luck!

Comment: @jagb please keep edits to only the necessary. Don't add more thanks as those are usually to be stripped anyway. Also, don't add code or example in the question, which it might change the intent of the author. If you want clarification, a comment is better. Don't make short sentences longer, as this doesn't help readability, in fact, it often hurt it instead. I highly encourage you to continue to edit questions as this helps a lot making SO better.

Comment: @EmileBergeron +1: Sorry, I'll never add code to the question again... I understand it would be better to write comment if it's needed to do so..

Answer (score -2):

You can use jQuery pagination, it is a much better solution.

Comment: i dont want to use jquery, i want to do it in php, you dont need to press the not usefull button on everything you dont like.

Comment: What if visitors turn off javascript? To write php code is possible . php will work very well as server sided code is better. Avoid jQuery and other javascript if there is no need to use it.  if a site does rely on client sided script you might experience more issues. javascript libraries should only be used to make your site more fancy but not as the main code to get your site to work